# Ruby getting undefined method `/' for Decimal(1596):Decimal (NoMethodError) for Decimal class

Tags: ruby

I have a function with calculates de displacement of a projectile on the screen. I wrote it running in a Ruby 2.2 environment in windows. Now I'm running the same code on linux with ruby 2.4 and getting this error:

> undefined method `/' for Decimal(1596):Decimal (NoMethodError)

I'm passing to the function the parameteres hpx, pxini, etc like `function Decimal.new(hpx,pxini...)` where each one can be a float or a int

```
require 'decimal'
#...
if tiro.hpx > tiro.pxini
                tiro.px += Std_Tiro_Speed * Math.cos(Math.atan((tiro.hpy - tiro.pyini) / (tiro.hpx - tiro.pxini)))
                tiro.py += Std_Tiro_Speed * Math.sin(Math.atan((tiro.hpy - tiro.pyini) / (tiro.hpx - tiro.pxini)))
            elsif tiro.hpx < tiro.pxini
                tiro.px -= Std_Tiro_Speed * Math.cos(Math.atan((tiro.hpy - tiro.pyini) / (tiro.hpx - tiro.pxini)))
                tiro.py -= Std_Tiro_Speed * Math.sin(Math.atan((tiro.hpy - tiro.pyini) / (tiro.hpx - tiro.pxini)))
            else
                if tiro.hpy > tiro.pyini
                    tiro.py += Std_Tiro_Speed
                else
                    tiro.py -= Std_Tiro_Speed
                end
            end
```

When running in windows the code run normally and updated the x and y position on the screen, now, it fails into an exception in the firsts call. What can be wrong?

Comment: Don't know anything about the gem (would generally suggest asking on their mailing list), but have you looked at http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/decimal/0.1.2  According to that site "Use like Float with few exceptions including Decimal#divide."